# SQL Server getting unique values for each product

Tags: sql-server, unique-values

I'm trying to make a query where it doesn't include products that have the same discount percent as another product. I'm also suppose to use a subquery. This is what I've came up with but I'm getting an error saying, "Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

```
SELECT ProductName,
 (SELECT DiscountPercent
 FROM Products
 GROUP BY DiscountPercent
 HAVING COUNT(DiscountPercent) = 1
 )
FROM Products

Fender Stratocaster 30.00
Gibson Les Paul 30.00
Gibson SG   52.00
Yamaha FG700S   38.00
Washburn D10S   0.00
Rodriguez Caballero 11  39.00
Fender Precision    30.00  
Hofner Icon 25.00
Ludwig 5-piece Drum Set with Cymbals    30.00
Tama 5-Piece Drum Set with Cymbals  15.00
```

Comment: SELECT ProductName,
 (SELECT DiscountPercent
 FROM Products P1 where p1.ProductName=p.ProductName
 GROUP BY DiscountPercent
 HAVING COUNT(DiscountPercent) = 1
 )
FROM Products P

Comment: It's not right. I'm still getting 3 of the same values on 3 products

Comment: provide sample data to get accurate result.
select * from 
(select *,row_number()over partition by(ProductName,DiscountPercent order by ProductName)rn  from Products)t4
where rn=1

Comment: I provided the sample data above

Comment: what version of sql server are you using? if it's sql server 2012, you have the possibility in a query to check the previous row returned for example : min(discount) OVER (ORDER BY [discount] ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING. Check on internet for more detail. If you have a 2005+ and not too many rows you should investigate in recurring query

Comment: Just so I understand you correctly: You want a result where every Discount exists excatly once and it does not matter which product it is, if the discount exists more then once?

Comment: I'm using SQL server 2012. Yes I need only unique values for the DiscountPercent.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
select * from (
select *,row_number()over (partition by Discount order by ProductName)rn from @t
)t4 where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
[ProductName],
[DiscountPercent]
FROM
(
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DiscountPercent ORDER BY ProductName) AS [ProductRank],
[ProductName],
[DiscountPercent]
FROM
[Products]
) AS Data
WHERE [ProductRank] = 1
```